# how to find the physical path of Http module Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule, ihttpmodule

In my web application we are using HTTP modules, this module has been registered as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="MyModule" type="com.Security.MyModule, MyModule, version=1.0.5873.52018, culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken=fegg50b0f0f4" preCondition="managedHandler" /> 
    <modules>
<system.webServer>
```

I want to edit the functionality of this module, where can I find the physical path of the above module.

Note: There is no assembly reference made for this module in the web application. The above Registration code in the Web.config file is the only link between the module and application.

Comment: An assembly referenced with the strong name can be found in `bin` subfolder, or in GAC (`%WINDIR%\assembly`). To check GAC you can start **Developer Command Prompt** and run `gacutil -l`.

Comment: Yeah it works i found MyModule in Gac Thank you,..

Comment: Hi Mark Shevchenko , i have another one dbout. if we want to deploy a dll into gac in a server machine which is not having Visual studio then how to install it??

Comment: You can find a short introduction in web deploing [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/02/19/how-to-package-com-component.aspx). Follow the links for details.

Answer (score 1):

I would search in the local directory, the bin and in the GAC. More information on assembly loading can be found [here...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720133.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You may also like to try [Fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).